# With respect to a web service, in the MVC paradigm, is the XML/JSON returned a property of the Model or a View

Tags: php, model-view-controller, design-patterns, yii

Two questions really:

1. When designing a RESTful web service in an MVC framework like Yii, should we consider the actual JSON or XML returned as a View (which makes sense to me, because rendered pages are views in the RESTful architecture of the web), or some derived property of a fat Model (i.e. `Controller->sendResponse(Model::JSONRepresenation());`
2. In Yii specifically, can I substitute other `Content-Type` idioms (like `application/json`) and try to wire the Views to make this work? OR is this a foolish endeavor? The [Yii guide to RESTful web services](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/) does not suggest the approach of mapping endpoint Actions to Views, which is what I would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

1. The MVC terms are meant to separate code sections, not classify the content sent to the client. So your question is analogous to asking if you should call the REST response a PHP or Perl output? You shouldn't call it either, generically. You can only call it one or the other specifically for your particular implementation. Nonetheless, In the [Yii Guide example](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/#hh6) that you referenced, the JSON/XML "page" requires no separate view file and is sent directly from the controller which formats the model in JSON, per your definition of a "fat Model".
2. I 'm not familiar with implementing the application/json idiom in Yii, but I can't imagine why you wouldn't follow the pattern in the canonical example provided by the Yii Guide.